# Calculate Surface Integral using Divergence theorem

Tags: divergence-operator

I have a basic question:

Using the divergence theorem, evaluate the surface integral $\iint v . dS$ where $S$ is the surface of the unit sphere centered on the origin and v is the vector $v=(y^2+2x)i-(z^2-2x)j-(x^2+2z)k$.

Comment: Search for "MathJax" and how to typeset math here so it's easier to read. Hint for your question: you'll probably want to consider spherical coordinates, and that $\iint_S v\cdot dS=\iiint_E \text{div}(v) \ dV$. So instead of integrating the vector field over the surface of the sphere($S$), you are integrating its diverence over the volume of the sphere ($E$).

Comment: yes, so for divergence I am to differentiate the i component with respect to x, the j component w.r.t y, etc.. and I get 0. Am I doing it wrong or is this the answer?

Comment: Yes. Zero is a common answer in many of these kinds of problems. It means the vector field has net flow zero through the sphere. If the vector field represented fluid flow, you would have fluid flowing in some places and out others, but the net flow through the sphere is zero.

Comment: thank you for your help :)

Comment: happy to be of assistance!